# How to fix handler duplicating commands list

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a handler which log commands list in console using ascii-table, but list of my commands gets duplicated, for example if I have 10 commands - list gets duplicated 10 times ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zBkK.jpg)). I use discord.js v12.5.3 and here is my code:

#### index

```js
["command"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handler/${handler}`)(client);
})
```

#### command.js (handler file)

```js
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");

const ascii = require("ascii-table");

let table = new ascii("Commands");
table.setHeading("Command", "Load status");

module.exports = (client) => {
  readdirSync("./commands/").forEach(dir => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
        for (let file of commands) {
            let pull = require(`../commands/${file}`);
    
            if (pull.name) {
                client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
                table.addRow(file, '✅');
            } else {
                table.addRow(file, `❌  -> missing a help.name, or help.name is not a string.`);
                continue;
            }
            if (pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name));
        }
    });
    // Log the table
    console.log(table.toString());
}
```

Comment: For each file, you read all the files... Why did you nest the readdirSync iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CherryDT I realized I just had to remove `readdirSync("./commands/").forEach(dir => {});` to fix my handler.